# How do we compute the gradients of recurrent connections in Tensorflow?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, tensorflow

As we unfold the network by time, the gradients of each time step is calculated. Are the recurrent gradients averaged or summed over the time steps in the Tensorflow implementation?

Answer (score 1):

The gradients are [averaged](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~urtasun/courses/CSC2541_Winter17/RNN.pdf) across time-steps. I would imagine this would be especially important if you had very large differences of input sequence length.